# How to append dependent columns into rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

The code to reproduce data is

```
 data = {
    'datetime': ['2019-01-01 08:03:00', '2019-01-01 08:04:00', '2019-01-01 08:04:00'],
    'own_mmsi': [236385000, 236385000, 244013009],
    'target_mmsi': [244013009, 244013009, 236385000],
    'own_lat': [59.330711, 59.330400, 59.327970],
    'own_lon': [10.515833, 10.514336, 10.515833],
    'target_lat': [59.327478, 59.327970, 59.330400],
    'target_lon': [10.515475, 10.515833, 10.514336],
    
}
```

An image of the sample df :
[image]

I wanted to get the target_lat and target_lon into lat lon columns and own_mmsi and target_mmsi into mmsi column which are dependent on datetime as each rows for entire df.

This is the desired first 2 rows of the output.

| datetime | mmsi | lat | lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 08:03:00 | 236385000 | 59.330711 | 10.515833 |
| 2019-01-01 08:03:00 | 244013009 | 59.327478 | 10.515475 |
| 2019-01-01 08:04:00 | 236385000 | 59.330400 | 10.514336 |

I tried to merge the df with melt and join logics and merge does no work wihtin the same df.

```
melted_df = pd.melt(
    df,
    id_vars=['datetime', 'own_mmsi'],
    value_vars=['target_mmsi', 'target_lat', 'target_lon'],
    var_name='attribute',
    value_name='value'
)

reshaped_df = melted_df.pivot_table(
    index=['datetime', 'own_mmsi'],
    columns='attribute',
    values='value',
    aggfunc='first'
).reset_index()
   
reshaped_df.columns.name = None  # Remove the name of the columns index
reshaped_df = reshaped_df.rename(columns={'target_mmsi': 'own_target_mmsi', 'target_lat': 'own_target_lat', 'target_lon': 'own_target_lon'})

print(reshaped_df)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here, and it isn't helped by the typos in your table (9.33 should surely be 59.33). Can you describe the business logic you tried to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are looking for [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').map(lambda x : '_'.join(x[::-1]))
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['mmsi', 'lat', 'lon'],
                                         i=['index', 'datetime'], j='var',
                                         sep='_', suffix='\w+')
         .reset_index('datetime').reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
              datetime       mmsi        lat        lon
0  2019-01-01 08:03:00  236385000  59.330711  10.515833
1  2019-01-01 08:03:00  244013009  59.327478  10.515475
2  2019-01-01 08:04:00  236385000  59.330400  10.514336
3  2019-01-01 08:04:00  244013009  59.327970  10.515833
4  2019-01-01 08:04:00  244013009  59.327970  10.515833
5  2019-01-01 08:04:00  236385000  59.330400  10.514336
```

Comment: I think you override `df` with the first line. It's `df.columns = ` not `df = `

Comment: Thank you @Corralien. Could you kindly explain how you did this. Just trying to learn.

Comment: First, you need to rename the columns because `pd.wide_to_long` expects the left part to be the stub name and the right part to be the observation name (j). The rest is explained in the function documentation :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`pivot_longer`](https://siuba.org/api/experimental.pivot.pivot_longer) from [**siuba**](https://siuba.org/):

```
from siuba import _
from siuba.experimental.pivot import pivot_longer

pivot_longer(df, ~_.datetime, names_to = [None, '.value'], names_sep = '_')

              datetime       mmsi        lat        lon
0  2019-01-01 08:03:00  236385000  59.330711  10.515833
0  2019-01-01 08:03:00  244013009  59.327478  10.515475
1  2019-01-01 08:04:00  236385000  59.330400  10.514336
1  2019-01-01 08:04:00  244013009  59.327970  10.515833
2  2019-01-01 08:04:00  244013009  59.327970  10.515833
2  2019-01-01 08:04:00  236385000  59.330400  10.514336
```